# Clique: Genesis File

Tags: go-ethereum, genesis, clique

What are the mandatory parameters of **`genesis.json`** File in PoA? and what are their expected values? for ex. values of

**`byzantiumBlock
epi155Block
DAOForkBlock
EIP150Block
EIP158Block
epoch
nonce
mixhash`**

When I tried to change the value of **`nonce`** and **`mixhash`** and then started the node, it did not start.

Answer (score 7):

Use something like this:

```
{
    "config": {
        "chainId": <yourChainId>,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip150Block": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0,
        "byzantiumBlock": 0,
        "clique": {
            "period": <yourPeriodInSecs>,
            "epoch": <yourEpochInBlocks>
        }
    },
    "alloc": {
        "0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": { "balance": "1" },
        "0000000000000000000000000000000000000002": { "balance": "1" },
        "0000000000000000000000000000000000000003": { "balance": "1" },
        "0000000000000000000000000000000000000004": { "balance": "1" },
        "0000000000000000000000000000000000000005": { "balance": "1" },
        "0000000000000000000000000000000000000006": { "balance": "1" },
        "0000000000000000000000000000000000000007": { "balance": "1" },
        "0000000000000000000000000000000000000008": { "balance": "1" },
        "<yourPreallocAccount>": { "balance": "<yourPreallocAmount>" }
    },
    "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "difficulty": "1",
    "extraData": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000<yourInitialSigners>0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "gasLimit": "<yourInitialGasLimit>",
    "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "nonce": "0",
    "timestamp": "<yourUnixTimeStamp>"
}
```

- `yourChainId`: Just use a number.
- `yourPeriodInSecs`: Block time in seconds. 5 or 10 are good values to start with.
- `yourEpochInBlocks`: The default of 30000 is usually good enough.
- `yourPreallocAccount`, `yourPreallocAmount`: Since no coins are created through mining, the preallocated amounts are all you have. Give an account some coins here. (No prefixed "0x".)
- `yourInitialSigners`: You need at least one initial signer. Add its account address here.
- `yourInitialGasLimit`: The initial gas limit per block. Depends on what you want to do. (Consider 21000 gas/transfer, for example.)
- `yourUnixTimeStamp`: The number of seconds since the Unix epoch (1970-01-01).

Notes:

- The other elements in `config` are optional; the way they are set here get you a blockchain that works like the current Ethereum (except for Clique). They control the blockchain behavior. You'll find more about what they mean by searching for them.
- The other accounts in `alloc` are predefined contracts that get initialized by this. Not strictly necessary but recommended.
- AFAIK, all the other genesis block elements must be like they are here.

Comment: What about `nonce` and `mixHash` values? If I try to change them I'm always getting error as ` ERROR[06-22|03:34:21] Failed to prepare header for mining      err="vote nonce not 0x00..0 or 0xff..f" `

Comment: I don't remember what `mixHash` is about, but the `nonce` value is used to vote authorities in and out and must always be one of the two values, as the error message says. In the genesis block, only 0 makes sense.